# Ruby idiom to shovel into a string or nil? (e.g. shovel or assign / safe shovel)

Tags: ruby, string, null, assign

I'd like to do this:

```
summary << reason
```

In my case, `summary` is a string, containing several sentences, and `reason` is one such sentence.

This works fine if the target already has a value, but sometimes `summary` can be `nil`. In that case, this raises:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

So, I could write something like this:

```
if summary 
  summary << reason
else 
  summary = reason
end
```

This is cumbersome and ugly. I can hide it away in a new method like `append(summary, reason)`, but I'm hoping there's a ruby idiom that can wrap this up concisely.

I've optimistically tried a few variants, without success:

```
summary += reason
summary &<< reason
```

In other scenarios, I might build an array of reasons (you can shovel into an empty array just fine), then finally join them into a summary...but that's not viable in my current project.

I also can't seed summary with an empty string (shoveling into an empty string also works fine), as other code depends on it being nil at times.

So, is there a "safe shovel" or simple "shovel or assign" idiom in Ruby, particularly for strings that might be nil?

Comment: For the safe navigation operator you must add a dot `.` (`'' &.<< 'foo'`, `nil .<< 'foo'`)

Comment: The easiest is to use the safe navigation operator. But depending on the context of your question, there might be a better approach.

Comment: But if `summary = nil` and you `summary &.<< 'foo'`, you're still left with `summary.nil?` being true. You're stuck because you have to change what `summary` refers to and the only sane way of doing that is to use an assignment. So why can `summary` be `nil` at all? Why can't you initialize it to an empty string?

Comment: Not simply `(summary ||= '') << 'foo'`? @muistooshort, I could imagine something like `['dog', 'cat'].find { |s| s == 'pig' } << "hello"`

Comment: @maxpleaner, alas, no Rails tag.

Comment: Still a comparison, but maybe a ternary statement?  e.g. `summary ? summary << reason : summary = reason`

Comment: Good ideas, everyone. There is no problem if `reason` is nil -- only if the destination of the shovel ('summary') is nil. The critical outcome is that the value of summary changes, so safe navigation operator doesn't help (much).

Comment: I *could* initialize `summary` with an empty string...except someone in a galaxy far, far away is running `.where('summary' is not null')` .  I'm more inclined to add an `if` to my code than go chasing down other people's code elsewhere.  @muistooshort And, these reasons can be added asynchronously, so I don't have very clear before/after points to initialize/clean up the summary.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I guess you could but I tend to prefer clarity over cleverness. Maybe an odd attitude in Ruby-land. I'd lean towards initializing `summary` or the OP's `Array#join` solution.

Comment: @DavidHempy You could start with an empty string, do whatever needs to be done, and then map empty strings back to `nil` before sending them into the database. I often do things like `self.whatever = whatever.to_s.mangle.presence` in Rails to hide a bunch of `nil` checks, the `#to_s` converts `nil` to `''` while leaving strings alone and the `#presence` call converts `''` to `nil` while leaving strings alone. Similar things apply to `nil`s that can be arrays or hashes as `NilClass#to_a` and `NilClass#to_h` do The Right Thing.

Comment: I like that last idea, @muistooshort. I didn't know that `''.presence` converted empty string to nil. I'll tuck that idea away for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with something like this; with the help of `||`.

```rb
summary = (summary || '') + reason
```

Or like so with the help of `||=` and `<<`:

```rb
(summary ||= '') << reason
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer @Oto Brglez's answer, but it inspired another solution that might be useful to someone:

```
summary = [summary, reason].join
```

This may or may not be easier to read, and probably is less performant. But it handles the nil summary problem without explicit alternation.

Comment: I actually like this better: straight forward and to the point without any unnecessary syntactical line noise or cleverness.